# Normal distribution for run schedule

Tags: distribution

I have an event that generates automatically once during a period of time, and I can't control it.
It can be 1 time in day or 60*60*24 times in day.
On ever iteration it gets the list of docs (from 0 to infinity) and process it.
On some of this iterations I need to run my action depending on some condition.
This condition is necessary to develop.

The main requirement is in difficulty finding an addiction between calls.
For example, if use 50% probability, in statistics we can see, that event runs at 1/2 of all runs this iteration. It's bad.
Direct dependency probability from len(docs) also is not good idea, because we can detect addiction while compare behavior on big and little docs selections.

However, we always can save all history of activity and use it.

Python interpretation os problem is finding the best "something" in this code:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def action():
  print 'Hello World!'

def get_docs():
  return []

while True:
  something = randint(1,2) % 2  # Need correct
  docs = get_docs()  # This functions return the docs: from 0 to infinity
  for doc in docs:
    if something:
      action()  # Some action that must run with normal distribution
  sleep(randint(1, 60*60*24))  # We can't change it
```

If someone knows researches or source code by this problem, or have any ideas, I will be very grateful for their presentation.
Thanks

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "addiction between calls". You seem to want to use a normal random variable, in which case you shouldn't be using `randint`. But, you have given absolutely no information about what the mean and standard deviation of that normal random variables is supposed to be.

Comment: That function is using to emulate activity of a person. So, website is using lots methods of detection that it is a bot. For example, real person can't "like" every second post that seen... I don't know, how to formulate the requirements more precisely.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШахов Could you add short description in Russian, please?